# Error cannot implicity convert object to string

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox, implicit-conversion

```
Random rnd = new Random();   
int DisAleatorio = rnd.Next(txtDistrito.Items.Count);
database[0, 2] = txtDistrito.Items[DisAleatorio];
```

So what im doing here is getting a random item from the comboBox "txtDistrito" and putting it on my string array "database" which i already declared before, but im getting the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string' on txtDistrito.Items[DisAleatorio], dont know why, please help me with that, thanks a lot.

Comment: I hate when decently-formed questions get downvoted because of the subject matter.  He's provided code, explained himself, and provided the specific error message he's getting.

Answer (score 4):

`txtDistrito.Items[DisAleatorio]` returns an `object`, while `database[i,j]` expects a `string`. You need to *cast* the object if you know it's a `string`

```
database[0, 2] = (string)txtDistrito.Items[DisAleatorio];
```

or *convert* it if the object may not be a string:

```
database[0, 2] = txtDistrito.Items[DisAleatorio].ToString();
```

Comment: thank, i really tought i had already done that, what a mistake